# search results different using deezer api on hosted node and client browser

Tags: api, azure, deezer

I'm searching using a server hosted on Microsoft Azure (hosted in dublin,ireland) If I `wget` using a search API on the Irish node,
i.e.:

```
wget "http://api.deezer.com/search/track?q=AN21 - Everything"
```

on this server I get:

```
{"data":[{"id":3972462,"readable":true,"title":"Black Spider","link":"http:\/\/www.deezer.com\/track\/3972462","duration":306,"rank":391291,"explicit_lyrics":false,"preview":"http:\....
```

which is different on my browser using the web-api search (based in France):

```
{"data":[{"id":96313320,"readable":true,"title":"Everything","link":"http:\/\/www.deezer.com\/track\/96313320","duration":272,"rank":533475,"explicit_lyrics":false,"preview":"http:\/\/cdn-preview-8.deezer.com\/stream\/87637bc3a17ec0376ce34ee7d19ba17d-2.mp3","artist":{"id":471649,"name":"AN21",
```

Is there a way to get all the data for the track irrespective of the location of the request origin?

In the example above the title "Everything" for example is not in the output from the hosted server, but the users of my site may have request access to it from their location.

Answer (score 1):

The tracks are according to your localization, there is no possibility to get the correct tracks from your country except if you provide the access token of the user in the request, so his country will be used to return the good tracks.